# Xdebug installed on EC2 Linux instance and using PhpStorm for remote debugging/development

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, xdebug

Here is my setup:

Debugging/developing from local environment

```
IDE:  PhpStorm 10
url for setting up my PhpStorm debugging:  https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/
PHP interpreter version (local copy): 5.6
```

Remote AWS ec2-linux setup:

```
xdebug for php56-devel 

I used this SO answer for my xdebug setup:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310833/installing-xdebug-on-php-5-6-amazon-linux-ami
```

and this xdebug configuration in my php.ini file on the remote server (ec2-linux):

```
Add to /etc/php-5.6.ini the following line :
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host= THE.IP.ADRESS.OF.THE.COMPUTER.THAT.WILL.REMOTE.DEBUG.THE.SERVER
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey = xdebug
```

but I'm still not getting any incoming connections in my PhpStorm from server or any debugging data I guess you call it.

What am I doing wrong? What did I miss?

Comment: Have you checked that port 9000 is open?

Comment: Are you using bookmarks or extension for starting Xdebug session? That url for setting up PhpStorm debugging is *really* old. Please refer to https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm.

Comment: Yes port 9000 is open.

Comment: wait do you mean if port 9000 is open on my local machine or on the linux server?

Comment: cause if your talking about local machine, then i tested telnet command: telnet localhost 9000  -  i got a blank cmd(black) screen which means it is open i'm assuming.

Comment: 1) I suggest checking this link (more up to date manuals; different aspects) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) Collect xdebug logs and see what it has to say: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . It's possible that IP might be wrong ..or that your server does not allow outgoing connections. If you have SSH connection to that server -- login and try `telnet` there

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP 5.4, Amazon Linux EC2 Instance. Installed PhpStorm on my system. Configured a deployment server over SFTP to my EC2 instance. Made Xdebug to start listening for requests.

I added the following lines to */etc/php.d/xdebug.ini* :

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.idekey=PhpStorm1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
```

**xdebug.remote_connect_back** makes sure that it is configured to the IP of the machine that is sending the request, i.e, the system on which I'm developing.

Don't forget to restart the server. Eg,

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Also, you must install the Xdebug helper extension for the browser you're testing on and enable it.